# Please make the tag [zookeeper] a synonym of [apache-zookeeper]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I see the tag [zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zookeeper) with 2 questions and [apache-zookeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-zookeeper) with 2k quesitons. Can you please make the former a synonym of the latter?

Comment: Looks like it has been completed

Comment: Makes sense I guess.